# Recursive type reports "Type instantiation is excessively deep and possibly infinite."

Tags: typescript

I am writing a utility to use with Jest that lazily creates an object mock as properties are accessed or invoked/called.

Basically, if a property is called like a method it will create or reuse a `jest.fn()` for that object path. If a property is accessed as a value (and the property hasn't been explicitly set previously) it will create another dynamic mock object on that property (recursively).

```js
const foo = new DynamicMock()

foo.bar.baz.buzz('Hello') // buzz() becomes a jest.fn() when called
console.log(foo.bar.baz.buzz.mock.calls[0][0]) // 'Hello'
```

I have written the utility and it works as expected (it's powered by Proxy objects) however I am having trouble typing to it.

The objective of the utility is to create a type that can satisfy object dependencies (like interfaces) and make the process of mocking dependencies during testing easier.

```js
interface Foo {
  bar(): void
}

let fooMock: DynamicMock<Foo>

beforeEach(() => {
  fooMock = new DynamicMock()
})

it('Should', () => {
  fooMock.bar // Should have type checking/completion for this property
})
```

I have created a type signature that does work but breaks when the mocked types contain recursive types.

```js
export type DynamicMock<T> = {
    [K in keyof T]: T[K] &
        (T[K] extends (...args: infer A) => infer B ? jest.Mock<B, A> : DynamicMock<T[K]>);
};

export type DynamicMockConstructor = {
    new <T>(): DynamicMock<T>;
    extend<T>(constructor: unknown): new <U extends T>() => DynamicMock<U>;
};

export const DynamicMock: DynamicMockConstructor;
```

```js
declare module externalPackage {
    export type JSONValue = null | void
        | boolean | number | string | Array<JSONValue> | JSONObject;

    export type JSONObject = {
        [key: string]: JSONValue;
    };

    export interface Bar {
        meta: JSONObject
    }

    export interface Foo {
        getBars(): ReadonlyArray<Bar>
    }
}

const mockFoo = new DynamicMock<externalPackage.Foo>()
const mockBar = new DynamicMock<externalPackage.Bar>()

mockFoo.getBars.mockReturnValue([mockBar]) // "Type instantiation is excessively deep and possibly infinite."
```

This results in the `Type instantiation is excessively deep and possibly infinite.` error (due to the recursive `JSONObject` type).

I can't change the code from an external package so I am wondering if there is anything I can do to my `DynamicMock` type signature to improve this condition?

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-ZxCD9UpAxxHNzUnVdmOfVi6gAYVmaUWCNfF+gdAIdn2d9qyYp8XzYpxuOzLplOQST8GoaT8HxdJJiUOBGF2OArkU0BtAAVSQrprF0JxqwIiA1NE5QHM0zNeNvfiQz09QeGE9S6lUljX2UCTQsMmTqACpDcx4XgA07cpym7bhQD0pBiBCghEWUMZiwZPZjy8mKlAOcLvPqVF0WUTEDjKxg3JIIqeCCJQK36WyT2iq86uqmimvIcEWuhA422rcpevag4ywrXADl60JwkiH0MDsXqKwcEggA)

Comment: You could possibly encode a depth limiter on `DynamicMock<T>` so that by default it would give up after some preset recursion depth like 5 or 6, as shown [in this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/mZvyom).  Does that meet your needs? If so I could write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Yeah that's great, I didn't know depth limits were a thing in TypeScript, thanks!

Comment: Anything is "a thing" if you build it yourself, I guess.  I'll write up an answer when I get a chance, but it's close to my bedtime so it might be in 8 or 9 hours.  In the meantime, if possible, please make sure it works for your needs so I don't write up an answer that turns out not to actually address your use case (these deeply nested types are always tricky like this and are often fragile with respect to slight changes in usage)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One potential approach to situations like this is to encode a depth limiter in your recursive type definition, so that when it "gives up" after some depth when it interacts with other recursive or deeply nested types.  Here's one way to do it for your example code:

```
type DynamicMock<T, D extends number = 9, DA extends any[] = []> = {
    [K in keyof T]: T[K] &
    (T[K] extends (...args: infer A) => infer B ? jest.Mock<B, A> :
        D extends DA['length'] ? any : DynamicMock<T[K], D, [0, ...DA]>);
};
```

The [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type parameter `D` is intended to be a numeric [literal type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) corresponding to the maximum depth to which we want to recurse before giving up.  I have it [default](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-3.html#generic-parameter-defaults) to `9` but you can specify other numbers.

The compiler can't directly do math on numeric literal types (see [ms/TS#26382](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26382) for a relevant feature request), so in order to "count to `D`" we use [variadic tuple types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-0.html#variadic-tuple-types) to prepend values to [tuples](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#tuple-types), whose `length`s can be checked.  So while "1 + 8 = 9" isn't directly representable, you can say "prepending an element to a tuple of length 8 yields a tuple of length 9".  Thus we use an accumulator type parameter `DA` to store this tuple.

Anyway, when the length of `DA` is equal to `D` then we've hit the base case and we return `any` instead of recursing.  Otherwise we lengthen `DA` by one element (`[0, ...DA]` is a new tuple type with a `0` prepended to it. And that `0` could be anything you want, since we only care about the length of the tuple. I chose `0` because it's a type whose name is short) and recurse.

---

If I try this on your code example the error goes away, as desired.

Whether or not this approach actually works for all required use cases isn't obvious, though.  Deeply recursive utility types often have weird edge cases.  It's possible that the depth limiter itself can interact badly with other recursive types, and you'd need to tweak or refactor it.  All I can suggest is that you should thoroughly test such deeply recursive utility types against a wide range of potential use cases before including them in any production-level code base.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-DR6i4DBXUKUBCzcioBVKlXlpwZ4ifWE0OhMVjsUAIVCo+jCZALJTFwRB83E8BDygjsd1NYQUwWEbWUXi6j9ACchnAcrXXR6rT6zUcLjtxXcdgA0iHQE7UIxJBkPRl7w5QAAyG9CDBdC-Y8N0wI4DlOc4Q0kCU5UIJoXFEGCd0jUAAH5QC4AgDnHbRI0MOUXFSf8tnAECrAgOU7AAcnYOATlyajvww2xQHSOdh1HXCgLvBwD0MOwAAZDHAw9nEIX1SgDbFszNUBCVnedF3HABhWYpRYQ08X6e0Ah2XZQD0Jwq3YpSuOXXQnEkrMuiMjBkHU-BqE0-A8XSSYlDgRhdjgK59MMgBVcjRksqsEIgMyl2UbQAqsjNpKnWTgwc9QeA4hdzOUUzOKipQ1NS5ytOoBK1xzHheCkjtynKTxdG4UAHKQYgUoIBFlDGIt6T2AdIvHA50uU5cUTRZQMQODrGGMkgWp4IIlHLfp-MHHK+oGzL6mG8gwVGqEDlbKtyjmiaDlLctcAOObQnCSJvQwOw5vLBwSHKIA)